# React Testing Library not updating state in input field

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm new to RLT, got this weird thing where I try to write a unit test for an input box, the RTL just won't update the state for input value, here's my testing code:

```
import { fireEvent, screen } from '@testing-library/dom';
import { act, render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from './Component';
    
describe('search input', () => {
  it('should update input field', async () => {
     const { getByTestId } = render(
        <Component />
      );
    
    const inputElement = getByTestId('search-text-input');
    expect(inputElement).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(inputElement).toHaveValue('');
    const country = 'usa';
    await waitFor(() => {
      fireEvent.change(inputElement, { target: { value: country } });
    });

    expect(getByTestId('search-text-input').value).toBe(country);
   });
});
```

and here's my react code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Component = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState<string>('');

  const onNameChange = React.useCallback((e) => {
    console.log('onNameChange...', e.target.value);
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  }, []);

  return (
      <input
        data-testid={'search-text-input'}
        autoComplete="off"
        name="search-input"
        onChange={onNameChange}
        size="medium"
        value={search}
        placeholder={'Search'}
      />
  );
};
```

As you can see, in my react code, when running the test, line 7 already prints 'usa', the value I'm passing in the test, but it seems like RTL just stuck here and won't update the state.

If anything helps, the project itself is in next.js, also dependency versions I'm having are:

```
"@testing-library/dom": "^8.18.1",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
"@types/jest": "^29.0.3",
"@types/node": "18.7.18",
"@types/react": "18.0.21",
"@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"next": "12.3.1",
```

Also tried this in another of my local repo with react 17.0.2, and no next.js, it passed; but it just won't pass with this react 18.2.0, and next.js repo...

Answer (score 0):

checked with a friend of mine, he asked me if both repo set the test env to browser, I checked, and yes they both set the testEnv to jsdom...

checked some other attributes in jest.config file, turns out the setupFilesAfterEnv attribute in jest.config file in the buggy repo is not corrected configed, the working repo utilize `@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect`, whereas the buggy repo is using a self defined js function...